# How to call collectionView.reloadData() from reusable header button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionview

I have a button in my reusable header view that deletes information in the array that  supplies the data for the collection view and header. I want it to also be able to perform `collectionView.reloadData()`.

The issue is that I can't call `collectionView.reloadData()` from the header button because it doesn't recognize collectionView as a variable. If I call `Builds().collectionView.reloadData()` (Builds is the View controller) the app crashes because it says that it found nil while unwrapping optional. I know that simply calling `collectionView.reloadData()` isn't the problem because i have `collectionView.reloadData()` called in `viewDidAppear()` and that gives me no crashes.

Whats going on here? How can I get my `collectionView` to reload data after the button removes the data?

For reference:

**Reusable Header:**

```
import UIKit

class BuildsHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

@IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var deleteBuildButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func deleteBuildButton(sender: UIButton) {

    for hero in heroes{ if hero.hero.name == heroForDetails.hero.name {
        hero.builds.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
        heroForDetails = hero
        }}

    saveToDefaults(userProfile)
   //Builds().collectionBuild.reloadData() runs just fine without this line
}
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class Builds: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionBuild: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionBuild.delegate = self
    collectionBuild.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    collectionBuild.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BuildCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TalentsCell {

            let build = heroForDetails.builds[indexPath.section]

            switch (indexPath.row) {

            case 0:
                cell.configureCell(build["1"]! as! Talent)
            case 1:
                cell.configureCell(build["4"]! as! Talent)
            case 2:
                cell.configureCell(build["7"]! as! Talent)
            case 3:
                cell.configureCell(build["10"]! as! Talent)
            case 4:
                cell.configureCell(build["13"]! as! Talent)
            case 5:
                cell.configureCell(build["16"]! as! Talent)
            case 6:
                cell.configureCell(build["20"]! as! Talent)
            default:
                cell.configureCell(build["1"]! as! Talent)

            }

            return cell

    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return heroForDetails.builds.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(50,50)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "BuildsHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BuildsHeader

    var buildDict = heroForDetails.builds[indexPath.section]
    header.headerLabel.text = buildDict["name"] as! String
    header.deleteBuildButton.tag = indexPath.section
    return header

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can do it with delegation.

Comment: @Sam_M is that really the only way? I'd have to add a bunch of lines of code for something that would normally take 1 line of code.  Also, I've read about delegation but never successfully executed it.

Comment: for each section is there a button

Comment: @AnuradhS yes, each section has its own button that deletes the information that corresponds to that section. I'll post a pic. Maybe there is a better way to design the page?

Comment: @Apple Yes that's the way to do this. Delegation isn't hard once you understand what's going on. I posted a detailed answer to a similar question before, I'll modify it for a collection view and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with delegation.

1. Create a protocol
2. Create a variable inside `BuildsHeader` for delegate
3. Call the delegate method in `deleteBuildButton` function

Now the code for `BuildsHeader` should look like this:

```
import UIKit

//**** The Protocol ****
protocol BuildsHeaderDelegate {
    func updateCollectionView()
}

class BuildsHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

    //**** Variable for the delegate ****
    var delegate: BuildsHeaderDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var deleteBuildButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func deleteBuildButton(sender: UIButton) {

        for hero in heroes{ if hero.hero.name == heroForDetails.hero.name {
            hero.builds.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
            heroForDetails = hero
            }}

        saveToDefaults(userProfile)
        //****  Call the delegate method ****
        self.delegate?.updateCollectionView()
    }
}
```

4. In the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method of your collection view configure the `delegate` property of the header, like this:

   ```
   let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "BuildsHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BuildsHeader
   //**** Set this view controller to be the header's delegate ****
   header.delegate = self
   // rest of header setup
   ```
5. Make the `Builds` ViewController confirm to `BuildsHeaderDelegate` :

   ```
   class Builds: UIViewController, BuildsHeaderDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
   ```
6. Implement `BuildsHeaderDelegate`'s delegate method in the `Builds` view controller. you can put this right after your `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method:

   ```
   func updateCollectionView () {
       //**** reload the collectionView ****
       self.collectionBuild.reloadData()
   }
   ```

Comment: Great that worked! Thanks so much. Could you or anyone else explain why I have to use delegation to make this work? What is the disconnect when the header and the view controller are talking to each other? This would help me understand when to use it in the future.

Comment: @Apple Delegation is useful when you want to pass information between objects. you don't have access to the collectionView within the BuildsHeader class and you can't reload it, so you send a message to the Builds viewController and tell it to reload the collectionView.

Comment: @Apple google "[ios delegation explained](https://www.google.com/#q=ios+delegation+explained)" and read more about it. one example for when to use it is your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647005/how-to-segue-from-child-view-controller-header-and-stay-within-parent-navigation) which can be solved with delegation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Delegate to call the method:

```
protocol BuildsHeaderDelegate(){
    func reloadCollectionView()
}

class BuildsHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

    var delegate:BuildsHeaderDelegate!

    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteBuildButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func deleteBuildButton(sender: UIButton) {

        for hero in heroes{ if hero.hero.name == heroForDetails.hero.name {
            hero.builds.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
            heroForDetails = hero
            }}

        saveToDefaults(userProfile)

        //##Call delegate method##
        delegate.reloadCollectionView()
    }

}
```

Conform delegate in View Controller and Assign it:

```
class Builds: UIViewController,delegate:BuildsHeaderDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionBuild: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionBuild.delegate = self
        collectionBuild.dataSource = self

    }

    func reloadCollectionView() {
        collectionBuild.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "BuildsHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BuildsHeader

        //##Assign Delegate##
        header.delegate = self

        var buildDict = heroForDetails.builds[indexPath.section]
        header.headerLabel.text = buildDict["name"] as! String
        header.deleteBuildButton.tag = indexPath.section
        return header

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no difference between this and the accepted solution. :)